# android sdk get broadcast auto renew subscription

Tags: android, broadcast, subscription, recurring

Is there any broadcast you can intercept when a subscription is automatically renewed? I need this to in order to send some info to my server when a new billing period starts. If there's no broadcast triggered, how do I know when a new subscription period starts?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about broadcast but you can save the subscription ending date in shared preferences and when app starts you can compare that date with the current date.If current date is greater , send info that you wanted to server

Comment: For the moment I used this approach. But I would have preferred a broadcast or something similar